# Are CRUD & FLS enforced with usage of Remote Objects?

Tags: security, javascript-remoting

I am wondering if CRUD & FLS are enforced when we are working with Remote Objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the documentation doesn't explicitly seem to mention this, it should be safe to assume that the underpinnings are using the REST API, which does honor FLS and CRUD (but, like the API, does not honor layout FLS).